# "error undefined" Opencart 2.2 admin dashboard while changing "Latest Orders" status

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I have installed opencart 2.2 with Journal 2.7.4 theme, when i try to change the status of order from admin dashboard, i come across an error "error undefined", Plz suggest to resolve this issue.[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBeHx.jpg)

Comment: did you find the solution to it?

Answer (score 1):

Because when you change the status, it runs an Ajax in the backend, with this Ajax response comes a bit of HTML error, so Ajax can't parse it, at that time it shows you this error.

And not in one way but in many ways this error comes like in OpenCart

1. Users must have API permission to change the order status, otherwise such an error may occur.
2. Often the URL is encoded in `&` before the token in the URL so the login page will come up so it will show an error.
3. Shows this error even when a warning comes in response.
4. Often this error occurs when the page is not working and the session expires.